# Hibernate load function left out of grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I noticed that the Grails hibernate plugin does not support the hibernate load function?  Does anybody know why that is?  In all of the documentation that I have seen, it seems that the accepted way to delete an object from a db is to do a get() with the object id followed by a delete().  While this works it makes an unnecessary database hit.  Was this a concious design decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in 1.0 and it wouldn't work because of a MetaClass issue, but it appears to work now. There's an open JIRA - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5406 - that I'll be implementing for 1.3.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response.  I personally think get(id, [lazy: true]) is a great interface for this feature.  This sounds like a fun task for me to learn how to write a grails plugin.